# Add random text after ?= in URL

Tags: javascript, php, html

Let's say this is the code for a page called `MyWebsite.com/page.php`

```
<?php
  $username = "SuperUsername";
  $password = "SuperPassword";
  if (isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p'] == "login") {
    if ($_POST['user'] != $username) {
        exit;
    } else if ($_POST['keypass'] != $password) {
        exit;
    } else if ($_POST['user'] == $username && $_POST['keypass'] == $password) {
    echo "LOGGED IN";
   } else {
    exit;
   }
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?p=login" method="post">
    <label><input type="text" name="user" id="user" /> Name</label><br />
    <label><input type="password" name="keypass" id="keypass" /> Password</label><br />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

As it is right now, if someone logs in, they get sent to a page called 'MyWebsite.com/page.php?p=login'

But right now, if someone goes to the website `MyWebsite.com/page.php?=1337` the same page without the `?=` query loads. How can I make it, so that I get whatever number is after the `?=` and when the user logs in, the same number, is added here `MyWebsite.com/page.php?p=login1337`.

How can I do that?

This is what I've attempted so far and it doesn't seem to work

```
$Query = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
if (isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p'] == "login" . $Query) {
/////////////////////
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?p=login<?php echo $Query;?>" method="post">
```

Comment: `page.php?=1337` is not a valid name-value pair

Comment: @HankyPanky I don't understand?

Comment: you need to name parameter for example page.php?id=1337 and in code $_GET['id']

Comment: if the value of `p` becomes `login1337` your login system will not work.

Comment: name 2 variables and url become something like page.php?p=login&id=1337 other two ways is to use substr/preg or mod_rewrite

Comment: I've updated the OP with an idea of how to fix it

Comment: @Robert Not sure why this doesn't work? I updated the OP

Comment: The question is: Why would someone go to `MyWebsite.com/page.php?=1337` ?

Comment: @musefan , I would. It's my website, No one is gonna be going on this page anyway, It's password protected

Comment: depsite the question if it's so simple why won't use use basic http authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could help... try this

```
$Query = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
if (isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p'] == "login") {
/////////////////////
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?p=login&q=<?php echo $Query;?>" method="post">
```

Like this you can get the $Query value with :

```
$Query = $_GET['q'];
```

Or another solution is to POST the p=login (not in URL) like this with a hidden input :

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?q=<?php echo $Query;?>" method="post">
<input typ="hidden" name="p" value="login" />
```

and in PHP you test :

```
if($_POST['p'] == 'login') {...}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you want me to do what instead..?

Comment: You could pass some arguments by POST instead of GET (Url) so your URL will stay unchanged.